# scipy.optimize minimize with dynamical multiple variable list

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use scipy.optimize to optimize. The problem I have is that the number of variable is not fixed – it is dynamically generated depending on the scenario. To capture this, I have to use if/elif statement to set the number of variable, which makes the code very bulky as shown below. Is there any elegant way to do this?

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

list1=['x','y'] # list1 is generated dynamically with varied length depending on different scenario. Here I just make len=2 as an example.


n=len(list1)
def f(params):
    if n==3:
        a, b, c = params 
        return a**2 + b**2 + c**2
    elif n==2:
        a, b  = params 
        return a**2 + b**2 
if n==3:
    initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
elif n==2:
    initial_guess = [1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess,method='SLSQP')
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this demo:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def cal_f(params):
    x = np.array(params)
    return np.sum(x ** 2)


def callist(list_l = ['a','b','c','d']):
    n = len(list_l)
    initial_guess = np.ones(shape=(n,))

    try:
        result = optimize.minimize(cal_f, initial_guess, method='SLSQP')
        if result.success:
            fitted_param = result.x
            print(result)
        else:
            raise ValueError(result.message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(Exception)


# test function
callist()

callist(list_l=['a','b', 'c', 'd','e','f'])
```